# Using lodash to filter an object property

Tags: filter, lodash

I'm trying to use the _.filter property to filter an array.  I'd like to use the matchesProperty shorthand, but don't want to do a straight comparison.

eg. This works:
    *.each(*.filter(this.across, ['len', 3]), dostuff);

but if I want to filter values less than 9, I need to use a function:
    *.each(*.filter(this.across, function (o) {return o.len<9}), dostuff);

Is there a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `dostuff` and `this.across` are, but let's assume you have an array of objects with property `len` and you want to filter values less than 9.

You can do this in a point free functional style, with just lodash, but it's going to look more convoluted than if you just use an arrow function. The `matchesProperty` shorthand only works for equality comparison, so can't be used in this case.

See both options below:

```js
const arr = [
  { len: 2 }, // keep
  { len: 5 }, // keep
  { len: 9 },
  { len: 22 },
  { len: 8 } // keep
]

// point free functional style
const filtered = _.filter(arr, _.flow(_.property('len'), _.partial(_.gt, 9)))


// with arrow function
const filtered2 = _.filter(arr, o => o.len < 9)

console.log(filtered)
console.log(filtered2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```